# NSScrollView not refreshing its document view in Mojave OSX 10.14

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, macos-mojave

Anyone having problems with your Custom NSView's inside a NSScrollView? I have a NSScrollView with a custom NSView that uses its draw(rect:) function to do all the work.

Before OSX 10.14, each time scrollview was marked with setNeedsDisplay, the documentView would also refresh. On OSX 10.14 I need to specifically mark the doucmentView to setNeedsDisplay too. Looks like its ignoring the NSScrollView.contentView.copiesOnScroll property.

Does anyone have similar issues or point me to release notes? the NSAppKit release notes don't say anything about NSScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

We encountered the same problem. After several days of experimenting, the cause for the problem in our setup was as follows:

The documents we need to draw can be quite large. Therefore we optimised drawing in NSView's drawRect method to paint the visible portions of the document only, according to the clip-rectangle:

```
NSRect clipRect = [nsClipView bounds];
```

This worked great before Mojave.

Under Mojave our code would display black for the portions of the document that scrolled into the visible region.

We changed our drawing routines to display **exactly** the areas indicated by the 'dirty rectangle' of the drawRect method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
```

Now scrolling works under Mojave.